# how to style a th element to look like a td

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, html-table

I have been tasked with switching out the TD elements for TH's on all the headers without any change in appearance.  Currently the only styling on the TD is:

```
td.detailColHeader {
    background-color:#d5d5d5;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

When I apply that to the th, it doesn't look the same.  Anyone know what needs to be added to make the TH look like the TD?

Comment: "doesn't look the same" is pretty ambiguous. Can you take a screenshot or something?

Comment: Are you sure there is no other CSS targeting TH because AFAIK td's and th's are semantically the same element.

Comment: `th { text-align:left; }`

Comment: Have you checked what browser defaults and inherited styles there are on the TD and TH elements? It's impossible to answer your question without more information. Do you have a link we can check?

Comment: @Phaeze `th` is a table header cell, which does differ semantically from a `td`, table data cell.

Comment: @ialarmedalien I know that, I meant that there are no implicit rendering differences, sorry if my comment did not make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

> The TH and TD elements are used for table cells. TH is used for table
>   header cells while TD is used for table data cells. This distinction
>   gives user agents a means to render such cells distinctly, for
>   instance by using a larger or heavier font for header cells. It is
>   also needed when rendering to speech. The CLASS attribute can be used
>   to further differentiate cells, for instance into heads and subheads.
>   This can be used together with style sheets to control the cell border
>   style, and fill color etc.

Practically the only change you have to do is:

```
td {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```css
td {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>th</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

After @Alohci you can also add:

```
th {
    text-align: left;
}
```

when table has fixed width.

```css
td {
    font-weight: bold;  
}

table{
    width: 200px;
}

th{
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>th</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>td</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The quote (given without indicating source= is from the HTML 3.0 draft, which expired in 1995. The statement about the difference is incorrect: there is also the difference that `th` content is centered by default, as opposite to left alignment for `td`.